# BeautifulSoup hicup on unique <td> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a table and aside from item number 5 there is no issue. Item seems to
have much more elaborate params.

I am bit confused as to why this is happening

Code I have is:

```
for row in tables.findAll('tr'):
    col = row.findAll('td')
    record =[]
    for i in range(0,9):
        cell = col[i].string.strip()
```

With "soup":

```
<td align="left" class="table-top">Item1</td>
<td align="left" class="table-top">Item2</td>
<td align="left" class="table-top">Item3</td>
<td align="center" class="table-top">Item4</td>
<td align="right" class="table-top">Item5 <img align="top" alt="" border="0" height="12" src="gfx/chart_hover_icon.gif" width="15"/></td>
```

First 4 get parsed but 5 gets an error:

```
cell = col[i].string.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

Your fifth `td` element contains more than one thing (some text and an `img`) so the `string` attribute is None.

You can use the `strings` or `stripped_strings` generators to pull this content - in this case you'd only have one return value, but it's worth thinking about how you want to handle a case in which there's text after the `img` as well.

> If there’s more than one thing inside a tag, you can still look at just the strings. Use the .strings generator
>
> These strings tend to have a lot of extra whitespace, which you can remove by using the .stripped_strings generator instead

Alternately, [`get_text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) will pull out the purely textual content, and gives you some options for controlling stripping and joining the text.